# Retrieving menu item using REST

Tags: routes, 8

I am looking for a way of getting menu items for a menu i.e(Main menu) via rest, enabling the Menu resource and trying `/entity/menu/{menu}`
gives me only dataset of the menu i.e

```
{
  "uuid": "57e695a4-2af8-43ac-9300-b989ecbb2d87",
  "langcode": "en",
  "status": true,
  "dependencies": [],
  "id": "main",
  "label": "Main navigation",
  "description": "Site section links",
  "locked": true
}
```

but I need the menu links associated to that menu too. 
which is the most suitable approach ?

Comment: Are you using browser plugin or something?

Comment: The solution for this was to create a custom rest plugin, I used drupal console to generate this.
https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/commands/generate-plugin-rest-resource.html

Comment: @Shabir yes I do use postman chrome extension, I try by php curl as well

Comment: There is discussion about this here https://www.drupal.org/node/2300677. It's currently not possible with D8 Rest API core. It also doesn't appear to be possible to create a View that exposes those items based on what menu they belong to. @DropDragon, can you provide an answer to your question with some more details. It would be super helpful!

Answer (score 1):

There is still no native way within Drupal core to expose config entities via REST. There are 2 contrib modules which claim to allow retrieving menu items via REST, neither of which I have used.

**[REST Menu Items](https://www.drupal.org/project/rest_menu_items)**

Allows you to specify maximum and minimum depth in the request.

**[REST Menu Tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/rest_menu_tree)**

Returns the menu tree. Not yet covered by Drupal's security advisory policy.

**Update 28 March 2017**

REST Menu Items works as advertised but check the [issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/rest_menu_items?categories=All) for any outstanding bugs. For example, currently the alias for a menu item isn't returned.